# Confused about nodes

Tags: python, linked-list

```
def absorb_value(lnk, value):
    """ (LinkedList, int) -> NoneType
    >>> lnk = LinkedList()
    >>> lnk.append(6)
    >>> lnk.append(7)
    >>> lnk.append(8)
    >>> lnk.append(7)
    >>> print(lnk.front)
    6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 7 ->|
    >>> absorb_value(lnk, 7)
    >>> print(lnk.front)
    6 -> 15 -> 7 ->|
    >>> absorb_value(lnk, 6)
    >>> print(lnk.front)
    21 -> 7 ->|
    """
    if lnk.front:
        prev_node, cur_node = None, lnk.front
        while cur_node and not cur_node.value == value:
            prev_node = cur_node
            cur_node = cur_node.next_
        if cur_node and cur_node.next_:
            cur_node.next_.value += value
            if prev_node:
                prev_node.next_ = cur_node.next_
            else:
                lnk.front = cur_node.next_
            lnk.size -= 1
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

There is a solution that I got, I understand most of codes but have no idea how it changed the original link.

```
 prev_node.next_ = cur_node.next_
```

Here I don't understand that how this code works, there is no code about `lnk`, but why `lnk` could be changed by it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you refer to at the end of your question cuts `cur_node` out of the linked list. It doesn't need to modify `lnk` directly because there will be a chain of other links leading to `prev_node` from `lnk`, so the change to the list will be visible.

I'd note that the whole `prev_node` business seems unnecessary to me. It would be easier to modify `cur_node.value` and remove `cur_node.next_` from the list, rather than removing `cur_node` after modifying `cur_node.next_.value`. (Maybe there's some corner case I'm not thinking of though? Are the `pass` statements at the end supposed to be replaced by some extra code?)